# Number of cells displayed in UI is less than the data count

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Guess my collectionView func for cellForItemAt is not called properly. 2nd and 3rd row count is missing.i.e the output of the row count is 
    row => 0
    row => 1
    row => 4
    row => 5
But my data count is 6 which is correct. Otherwise the 4 cells displayed are perfect with image and other data.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        var row  = indexPath.row
        print ("row =>", row)
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        var imgURL: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["src"] {
            imgURL = "\(object)"
        }
        let url = URL(string: imgURL ?? "")
        cell?.cellImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), completed: {
            [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL)
            in
        })
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        var shoptitle: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["shop_name"] {
            shoptitle = "\(object)"
        }
        cell?.txtDescription.text = shoptitle
        cell?.shareIcon.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell?.shareIcon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        cell?.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        return cell!
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print(String(format: "Data Count :%lu", UInt(dataSource.count)))
        return dataSource.count
    }
```

Comment: No matter what you have in your `cellForItemAt`, the number of rows is determined by `numberOfItemsInSection`. So, you should share the code you have in that delegate.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yeha updated the code. the print statement for the data is ==> Data Count :6

Comment: Where are you storing cell that you created in cellForItemAt?

Comment: Also, are there any other methods implemented that handle indexPaths separately?

Comment: are you sure there is any image in cell 2 and 3 ?
Print your dataSource and show us data in there?

Comment: @uma collection view cell are lazily loaded when required meaning cellForItemAt is called lazily.  If you try scrolling the collection view, maybe  cellForItemAt might be called for row 2 and 3. If not called some more code snippets will be required.

Comment: @PGDev its an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the `cell` as instance variable.

Replace

```
cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
```

with

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
```

**Edit:**

Use `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` to get cell in `didSelectItemAt` method.

Comment: but i need this "cell" in didSelectItemAt also , so if i declare it inside cellForItemAt alone then it would be out of scope in didSelectItemAt

Comment: Keeping a single cell instance won't even solve your purpose either. Get cell in  didSelectItemAt using `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`

Comment: i am using UICollectionView and not tableView. do we still have this function in UICollectionView... please let me know if yes.

Comment: Yes. Its `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)`

Comment: yeah its like that.. but it still the same. the same data source when quried from the objective c app, its working fine. i am not sure what is missing, might be a silly mistake but could not figure it out.